# Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router::fallback()

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I would like to create a REST application 404 response,

I have added the below code at the bottom of the router page,

```php
$app->router->group([
    'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
], function ($router) {
    require __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php';
});

$app->router->fallback(function () {
     return response()->json(['success' => false],404);
});
```

I'm getting the below exception!
Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router::fallback()
[image]

But from the laravel documentation, I can use this method for 404 page. it's not working in lumen.
[image]

Can anybody help to solve this issue?

Comment: There's no fallback method on lumen.

Comment: @EliasSoares How can I achieve the 404 pages? please don't suggest the try-catch method.